# Bind a routevalue to a property of an object that is part of viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modelbinders

I have the following route:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
```

and I use the ViewModel:

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    public class ProductViewModel
    {

        public ProductViewModel()
        {
            ProductDetail = new ProductInfo();
        }

        public ProductInfo ProductDetail { get; set; }

    }

    public class ProductInfo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
    }

}
```

I need a way to bind the parameter id of the route to Model.ProductDetail.ProductID.

/Products/Display/2 should lead to :

Model.ProductDetail.ProductID == 2

I know this looks a bit strange: It would be much simpler if my ViewModel would only be

public class ProductViewModel{ public int Id {get;set;}}

For handling partials I prefer to use aggregation. I realy cant have ID in the main ViewModel class.

I am pretty shure that I need to implement my own ModelBinder, but I dont see where I should implement my own rules.

How can I map the route parameter "id" to the property Model.ProductDetail.ProductID ?

EDIT:

Here is how its done -

```
    public class ProductModelBinder: DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override void BindProperty(
        ControllerContext controllerContext,
        ModelBindingContext bindingContext, 
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor
        )    {
            if (bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(ProductViewModel)
            && String.Compare(propertyDescriptor.Name, "ProductDetail", true) == 0)     
            {         
                int id = int.Parse((string)controllerContext.RouteData.Values["id"]);
                ProductViewModel productView = bindingContext.Model as ProductViewModel;
                productView.ProductDetail.ProductID = id;           
                return;       
         }       
        base.BindProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor);    }
}
```

Comment: But this won't populate productView.ProductDetail.Name, or anything else in the ViewModel. It will basically give you a useless ProductViewModel object since only the id is filled in.

Comment: I guess my example is not so nice. In the real application I only need the id in ProductDetail. The other properties are filled inside the controller by accessing the repository.

Comment: A better practice would be: ActionResult Details(int id) { return View(new ProductViewModel(db.GetProductInfo(id))); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this (not tested):

```
public class CustomModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override void BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)
    {
        if (bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(ProductInfo)
            && String.Compare(propertyDescriptor.Name, "ProductID", true) == 0)
        {
            var id = (int)controllerContext.RouteData.Values["id"];

            var productInfo = bindingContext.Model as ProductInfo;

            productInfo.ProductID = id;

            return;
        }

        base.BindProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you eugene. This worked. I had to build a ModelBinder for ProductViewModel. You showed the binder for ProductInfo. I am not shure if I can register a binder for a subobject. Anyway it works for me as shown in the updated post .