# MVC and routing with strong typed views?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, strongly-typed-view

**Hi,**

Say that I got a action that returns to a strong typed view. This type is also the inparameter to the action. To set the current page number(for a list on the page) I need to set Model.ALS.P (our strong type).

When sending a requestion to the servier the quarystring myComputer.com/MyController/MyAction?ALS.P=2 will set the ALS.P to 2 on the incoming object to the action.

If I want to convert this to the following URL : myComputer.com/MyController/MyAction/2 how would the route look like?

I have tried this :

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "List", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{ALS_P}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Ad", action = "List", ALS_P = 0 } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

But that do not work and it will not accept ALS.P as parameter name.

**BestRegards**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know the route you're defining is the same as the default route in asp.net mvc? That means, if you didn't remove the default route definition, yours will never get hit.

You should leave the default route, and create a custom modelbinder to bind the id routeparameter to the appropriate property of your model. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075129/bind-a-routevalue-to-a-property-of-an-object-that-is-part-of-viewmodel) for more detail.

Otherwise, there's also the [routedebugger](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/routedebugger) (available from nuget) which can show you more insight into your routes and how (when) they are hit.

Comment: Okay so to get the ALS_P / Id to bind with my Model.ALS.P I have to extend the DefaultModelBinder?

Comment: You have to create a custom ModelBinder. This can be accomplished by deriving from DefaultModelBinder yes and is recommended in this case, but that is not necessary in that you can also implement the IModelBinder interface, but then you have to do more work.