# ActionMethodSelectorAttribute unable to access types?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, class, controller, asp.net-membership

I am relatively new to MVC3, and am developing a website that will need to handle pre-loaded accounts in the default Microsoft membership provider, using SQL Server, EF4, etc.  Some progress has been made, and with the help of someone on SO, I have got the ActionMethodSelectorAttribute working correctly to help me with that.

I.e., when we see someone's ID as part of their attempt to load a profile page (www.mysite.com/profile/4) we will look to see if that ID/account has been 'claimed' or not.  (My original posting is here: [MVC3 using routes or using controller logic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10594013/mvc3-using-routes-or-using-controller-logic))

Unfortunately, inside the ActionMethodSelectorAttribute, I am having a heck of a time doing a relatively simple database call to determine if the account is claimed/not claimed.

Here is my current state of the code:

```
    public class UserAccountActivatedAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
    {
        public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo)
        {
            if (controllerContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("controllerContext");
            }
            // get profile id first
            int id = int.Parse((string)controllerContext.RouteData.Values["id"]);
            var profile = db.Profiles.Where(q => q.ProfileId == id).FirstOrDefault();
            bool isActivated = profile;// some code to get this state 
            return isActivated;
        }
    }
```

The line

```
var profile = db.Profiles.Where(q => q.ProfileId == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

errors on the db. section, with error message as follows:

> Cannot access a non-static member of outer type 'MySite.Controllers.HomeController' via nested type 'MySite.Controllers.HomeController.UserAccountActivatedAttribute'

...with the error being highlight under the db.

Does anyone know why, inside the ActionMethodSelectorAttribute, I cannot seem to make this call?  (NOTE: inside the same Home controller, I am making many similar calls in Public ActionResult and ViewResult classes without any errors.)

**EDIT**

My HomeController.cs looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MySite.Models;

namespace MySite.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private MySiteEntities db = new MySiteEntities();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to MySite.com!";
        return View();
    }
    //several other ActionResults - create, delete, etc.

    public class UserAccountActivatedAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
    {
    public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        if (controllerContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("controllerContext");
        }
        // get profile id first
        int id = int.Parse((string)controllerContext.RouteData.Values["id"]);
        var profile = db.Profiles.Where(q => q.ProfileId == id).FirstOrDefault();
        bool isActivated = profile;// some code to get this state 
        return isActivated;
    }
    }
```

...definitely it falls inside the Home Controller.

**EDIT #2:**

Closer, but a small issue with the value always being TRUE.

```
public class UserAccountActivatedAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    private MySiteEntities db = new MySiteEntities();

    public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        if (controllerContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("controllerContext");
        }
        int id = int.Parse((string)controllerContext.RouteData.Values["id"]);
        var data = new MySiteEntities();
        var claimed = db.Claimeds.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ProfileId == id);
        bool isActivated = claimed.Claimed1.Value != null;
        return isActivated;
    }
}
```

The claimed.Claimed1.Value != null; gives me a warning: The result of the expression is always 'true' since a value of type 'bool' is never equal to 'null' of type 'bool?'

However, I have to have something there to handle a NULL value, right?

Comment: `bool` can never be null. Only `bool?` can be null. Is claimed.Claimed1.Value a `bool` or a `bool?` type..? If it is `bool`, you do not need a null check, since it can never be null. If it is a `bool?` on the other hand, check null using this: `bool isActivated = claimed.Claimed1.Value.HasValue;`

Comment: Somehow I missed this, but I will use it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code actually looks more like this, am I right?

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public class UserAccountActivatedAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

You need to make the attribute class a first-level class, not nested within the controller. You then need to give it its own db instance.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    ...
}

public class UserAccountActivatedAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    private readonly CustomDbContext db = new CustomDbContext();

    public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, 
        MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        // original code here
    }
}
```

The reason for this is because when the attribute class is nested within the controller class, it cannot access the `db` instance variable, because it is not a static variable. Your attributes should really not be nested classes, and should have their own separate instance variables. **In other words, don't try to solve this by making the controller's `db` variable `static`.**

Comment: Aha!  I did not know that.  I'll edit my question to show what it actually looks like, and then try to investigate this.  Thanks, Dan!

Comment: I have to make sure that some of my ActionResults that are still inside HomeController, but dependent on the ActionMethodSelectorAttribute, will still work.          [ActionName("Profile")]
        public ActionResult IndexNonActivated(int? id)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Claimed", new { id = id });
        }

Comment: The ActionMethodSelectorAttribute does not have to be in the same class or file as your controller. You apply an attribute to the controller using the `[UserAccountActivated]` syntax on the action method. Go back and re-read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10613782/304832

Comment: I still don't have it working right, but I'm a lot closer; thanks for all your posts, Dan.